# discord.py How to make a emoji guess game?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Hi i am making a Discord bot and i wanted to add a fun command that asks a emoji about a film and it wants you to answer properly. How am i suppossed to do that? Btw here is my code;

```
@client.command()
async def emoji(ctx):
    filmemojis = [':woman_frowning: :sparkler: :woman_with_veil: :high_heel:',
                  ':ocean: :fish: :mag:',
                  ':nerd: :man_mage: :sparkler: :school:',
                  ':tiger2: :person_wearing_turban: :man_rowing_boat:',
                  ':ring: :crown: :volcano:',
                  ':earth_americas: :rocket: :monkey_face:',
                  ':rocket: :alien: :sunglasses: :sunglasses:',
                  ':mouse2: :pizza: :turtle: :turtle: :turtle: :turtle:',
                  ':mushroom: :grinning: :weary: :smirk: :triumph: :open_mouth: :innocent: :pensive:',
                  ':ship: :couple_with_heart_woman_man:',
                  ':blue_car: :watch: :arrow_right_hook: :hourglass_flowing_sand:']
    await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(filmemojis)}\nWhat film is this?')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`Bot.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

```py
@client.command()
async def emoji(ctx):
    filmemojis = [
        ':woman_frowning: :sparkler: :woman_with_veil: :high_heel:',
        ':ocean: :fish: :mag:',
        ':nerd: :man_mage: :sparkler: :school:',
        ':tiger2: :person_wearing_turban: :man_rowing_boat:',
        ':ring: :crown: :volcano:',
        ':earth_americas: :rocket: :monkey_face:',
        ':rocket: :alien: :sunglasses: :sunglasses:',
        ':mouse2: :pizza: :turtle: :turtle: :turtle: :turtle:',
        ':mushroom: :grinning: :weary: :smirk: :triumph: :open_mouth: :innocent: :pensive:',
        ':ship: :couple_with_heart_woman_man:',
        ':blue_car: :watch: :arrow_right_hook: :hourglass_flowing_sand:'
    ]


    await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(filmemojis)}\nWhat film is this?')

    def check(m):
        """Checks if the user that replied is the same as the one that invoked the command"""
        return m.author == ctx.author

    message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check) # You can also add a timeout
```

Adding a timeout

```py
try:
    message = await client.wait_for('message', check-check, timeout=60.0) # Change the timeout accordingly
except asyncio.TimeoutError: # You need to import asyncio for this
    await ctx.send('whatever')
```

Comment: Thank you! But i have a problem, you know this is not just a one question, it has a LOT questions i mean emoji's so, how am i supposed to make a check for specific emoji question?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: As an example, in the `filmemojis` list `':woman_frowning: :sparkler: :woman_with_veil: :high_heel:'`thingy will send this message: https://ibb.co/c6BFSz7 if someone says 'Cindrella' bot will say 'Correct Answer!', well this is the easy part but the hard one is that, i need to make this for every each one of them. I hope you did understand. (If you still didn't understand here is an another example; `':ocean: :fish: :mag:'` this will send https://ibb.co/ZKWPqGx this and if someone says 'Nemo' bot will say 'Correct Answer!' and i should make this for every each one of them.)

Comment: Simply map the movies to it's emojis in a dict like so `film_emojis = {'cinderella': ':woman_frowning: :sparkler: :woman_with_veil: :high_heel:', ...}`, get a random movie and in a while loop keep asking the user until he answers correctly

Comment: Check the edit, also remember to accept the answer if it helped